# Unable to perform silent print :java

Tags: java

Why this below code ask to choose printer everytime when i run ? I am trying to perform silent print at once whenever i run this below code.

Is there any way how to set printer only once?

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Sides;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
public class PdfBoxPrint { 

    public static PrintService choosePrinter() {
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        if(printJob.printDialog()) {
            return printJob.getPrintService();          
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException, PrinterException {
       DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet patts = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        patts.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
        PrintService[] ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, patts);
        if (ps.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No Printer found");
        }
        System.out.println("Available printers: " + Arrays.asList(ps));//Prints default: "Available printers: [Win32 Printer : Fax]"

        // Locate the default print service for this environment. 
        PrintService myService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService(); 
        // Create and return a PrintJob capable of handling data from

        // any of the supported document flavors.
        System.out.println("Default Printer: "+myService.getName()); 


        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintService(choosePrinter());

        URL myURL = new URL("[SOME LINK TO A PDF]");
           PDDocument pdf=PDDocument.load(myURL);

        pdf.silentPrint(job);

    }
}
```

Comment: if you are on windows try to set a default printer via `Devices & Printers`

Comment: @JavaBond Don't know, how to do that? -any suggestion

Comment: For windows 7: Go to start --> Devices and Printers. Here select the printer, right click and choose 'Set as default printer' from menu

Comment: @JavaBond i have already did that.  can try the above code in ur system?

Answer (score 0):

You grab the default printer with

```
PrintService myService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
```

But then you toss it away with

```
job.setPrintService(choosePrinter());
```

If you want the default printer, use it.  If not, prompt.  If you only want to prompt the **first time**, well, then you have a data persistence problem and you should be storing your preferences somewhere and then re-loading them at a later time.  When you load them, use your `PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices` to match, set print service, etc.